# deploy two applications on the same domain on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I have a back end api deployed on heroku,

```
mydomain.com
```

The front end is an angularjs application, I want to host it on the same url so that I will avoid the cors restriction.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Highly doubt it - you may be able to do it with multiple dynos

Comment: Yeah, generally you could spin up a reverse proxy like nginx or haproxy dyno (like described [here](https://pilot.co/blog/hosting-multiple-heroku-apps-on-a-single-domain/)) or use a CDN, but those approaches can be kind of involved, which is why I built https://routepath.app

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways to solve this:

1. by using [Multiple Buildpacks on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) and [buildpack-nginx](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) you can have a nginx instance in your dynos that can serve your static files, and also pass requests to your backend server (unicorn) processes. 
   The frontend code has to reside inside the same repo as the backend code, or (as an alternative) be pulled out of a different repo in the build process.
2. similar to the first solution, but without nginx. Possible if you get ruby/unicorn to serve your static JS files too.
3. use [Heroku's Docker Support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker) to build your own app image and deploy it.
4. All of the above combined :)

This most likely could include adding the nodejs buildpack to setup a proper build pipeline.